# NSMenuItem setTitle with columns

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I want to set a title like

Name:________Rank:

blbalb_______5

aksjdnaas____6

123123123..._7

q____________8

Assume that `_` = blank

Is it possible ?
If so can someone guide me how ?

I tried to do it this way

```
- (NSString *)getFromatedAppDescription
{
//    NSMutableString * formatedString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    NSString * name = _userName;
    if ([name length] > MAX_NAME_LENGTH)
    {
        name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",[name substringToIndex: MAX_NAME_LENGTH - 3]];//Truncate Tail
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-15s %d",[name UTF8String],_rank];
}
```

But it fails :(

**EDIT:**

I solved it by creating `NSView` and adding there `NSTextFields` But I ended up with 5 `NSTExtFields` And I doubt it is inefficient solution :-( I would still like to see some tips from people here because I eager to improve the performance as much as I can

Comment: The code looks right, what have you get?

Comment: Well characters has distinct width :-( char i is about 2 pixels while char m 5 :-(

Comment: I solved it by creating `NSView` and adding there `NSTextFields` But I ended up with 5 `NSTExtFields` And I doubt it is inefficient solution :-(
I would still like to see some tips from people here because I eager to improve the performance as much as I can

Comment: Maybe I you can choose a `monospaced font` for your text. please see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the font of your text to a Monospaced font, see the [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `attributedTitle`(`NSAttributedString*`) of an `NSMenuItem`and set a right- or decimal-aligned tab stop using an `NSTextTab` attribute on the `NSMutableParagraphStyle` of the `attributedTitle` (and just add a tab between the label and the value in the string of the `attributedTitle`).

Comment: Thanks, this worked after I also set the `defaultTabInterval` on the `NSMutableParagraphStyle`